# How to change Vuetify v-autocomplete menu border radius style?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-autocomplete

I want to change the box style of the `v-autocomplete` drop-down list and give a `border-radius` style to the drop-down list, as you can see in the image below.

[image: link to example image]

What I have designed so far is like the image below.

[image: Link to my work image]

So far, I've given the menu-props property directly to the `v-autocomplete` tag:

```html
<v-autocomplete
  :menu-props="{
    nudgeBottom: 15 + 'px',
    zIndex: 2,
    allowOverflow
  }"
  :items="searchBarInfo"
  rounded
  outlined
  filled
  clearable
  item-color="deep-purple"
  height="50"
  placeholder="Search the ..."
  color="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)"
  background-color="white"
  prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
  class="my-text-style "
  :no-data-text="($vuetify.noDataText = 'Nothing found')">
</v-autocomplete>
```

The above code only adds the `v-autocomplete` tag but not the `border-radius` style.

Is there a way to make something like the image you see with Vuetify's `v-autocomplete`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `menu-props: { rounded }`

For Vuetify's rounded menu borders, you can use the menu property called `rounded` to avoid modifying CSS directly.  Pass it along with the other `menu-props`:

```html
:menu-props="{
  nudgeBottom: 15 + 'px',
  zIndex: 2,
  allowOverflow,
  rounded: 'xl'      // <-- Here ✅
}"
```

On the Vuetify [Border radius](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/border-radius/) page you can see some of the values it accepts:

- 0
- sm
- md
- lg
- xl
- pill
- circle

The `xl` value seems to match your image best.  Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/sh0ber/pen/JjRmYwN)

#### -or- Modifying CSS

Or if you want to modify the CSS directly, use a more specific selector than the Vuetify default.  For example:

```css
.v-application .v-autocomplete__content.menuable__content__active {
  border-radius: 100px !important;
}
```

<sup>`!important` is necessary for superseding Vuetify's own `!important`</sup>